# Is there a R function to derive a "kink"

Tags: r, optimization

Suppose I have a function with a kink. I want to derive a kink point, which in this case is `0.314`. I tried `optim` but it does not work.

[image: A function with a kink]

Here is an example. In general, I want to derive `c`. Of course, I could use brute force, but it is slow.

```
# function with a kink
f <- function(x, c){
  (x >= 0 & x < c) * 0 + (x >= c & x <=1) * (sin(3*(x-c))) + 
    (x < 0 | x > 1) * 100
}

# plot
x_vec <- seq(0, 1, .01)
plot(x_vec, f(x_vec, c = pi/10), "l")

# does not work
optim(.4, f, c = pi/10)
```

Comment: You might be interested in the segmented package. It only works for linear models but would give a decent estimate of the breakpoint if you use a quadratic model as an approximation in this example.

Comment: The numerical first derivative would be discontinuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function has no unique minimum.

Here, a trick is to transform this function a little bit, so that its kink becomes a unique minimum.

```
g <- function (x, c) f(x, c) - x

x_vec <- seq(0, 1, 0.01)
plot(x_vec, g(x_vec, c = pi/10), type = "l")

# now works
optim(0.4, g, c = pi/10, method = "BFGS")
#$par
#[1] 0.3140978
#
#$value
#[1] -0.3140978
#
#$counts
#function gradient 
#      34        5 
#
#$convergence
#[1] 0
#
#$message
#NULL
```

[image: g]

---

**Note:**

In mathematics, if we want to find something, we have to first define it precisely. So what is a "kink" exactly? In this example, you refer to the parameter `c = pi / 10`. But what is it in general? Without a clear definition, there is no algorithm/function to get it.